# Abstract class and inheritance

Tags: c++, oop

```
class MyInterface {
public:
    virtual void someFunction()= 0;
};

class X: public MyInterface {
private:
    virtual void doThis() {
        printf("This X");
    }
    virtual void doThat() {
        printf("That X");
    }
public:
    void someFunction() {
        doThis();
        doThat();
    }
};

class Y: public MyInterface, private X {
private:
    void doThat() {
        printf("That Y");
    }
};

MyInterface *iface= new Y();
Y->someFunction();
```

Coming from `Java`'s flavor of OOP, I am trying to wrap my head around the OOP model of C++. I have read this: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm for suggestions how to design interfaces in C++. The above code is a direct application (or a slight variation thereof) of the rule the author expounds. My question is, is the code above going to produce "This X" followed by "That Y"? What I find confusing is that the author recommends using `virtual` in conjunction with `private`. My reasoning is, if a function is `private`, how are we to override it at all?
In the above code, it is granted that `Y` can be used as the right-hand-side of the assignment, since we derive publicly from the interface. When we call `someFunction()` on it, since we do not explicitly provide any implementation inside `class Y`, is it going to use the implementation from `class X`? Then, provided it does, it looks at `doThat()` and again uses `Y`s implementation of it?

Comment: Actually that code won't compile, because you're initializing a `MyInterface` with an  `Y*` .

Answer (score 1):

The code has a few problems. Here is a working example:

```
class MyInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~MyInterface() { }
    virtual void someFunction() = 0;
};

class X : public MyInterface
{
private:
    virtual void doThis()
    {
        printf("This X\n");
    }
    virtual void doThat()
    {
        printf("That X\n");
    }

public:
    void someFunction()
    {
        doThis();
        doThat();
    }
};

class Y : public X
{
private:
    void doThat()
    {
        printf("That Y\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyInterface *iface = new Y();
    iface->someFunction();
    delete iface;
}
```

### Explanations

1. You need to use `class Y : public X` to be able to use the implementation of `void X::someFunction()`

   Unfortunately there is no real interface in C++ and there is only a workaround using pure virtual class. This workaround with two parents has it's own limitations *(see bellow)*. And therefore it is also a good idea to add a destructor to interface definition.

   When you use `class Y: public MyInterface, private X` you need to provide a custom implementation of `MyInterface::someFunction()`. You have have two parent classes and `someFunction()` in both parents *(`X` and `MyInterface`)*. This is necessary even when there is only one implementation of function. Therefore you need to specify which parent class 'implementation' will be used. Error:

   > 'Y': cannot instantiate abstract class

   You also get a error when you remove the interface *(try to use the interface from `X`)*. The reason is simple, when `X` is private, the implementation is not public and can not be used as a interface.

   > 'type cast': conversion from 'Y *' to 'MyInterface *' exists, but is inaccessible
2. You are using class as type in `Y->someFunction();`
3. I have no idea, why you can override a private virtual function. I mostly work in C# now and this 'feature' of C++ is something I do not get. You are right, that this should be bad code, but it work *(at least in Visual Studio 2017)*.

   I would also like to know, why this is not considered as error/incorrect code construction.